# How to wake on SSH with NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager, wake-on-lan

How do I persist a wake-via-ssh setting with NetworkManager?

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421325/wake-on-lan-via-ssh) and the [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Enable_WoL_on_the_network_adapter) that it cites, I can enable Wake-on-LAN with a magic packet using,

```
# ethtool -s <interface> wol g
```

and have it wake on ssh by using `u` for `unicast` instead of `g` for `magic`.

The Arch wiki later states I can persist a wake-on-LAN with NetworkManager with:

```
# nmcli c modify "<my-connection>" 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic
```

However, I want to persist wake-on-ssh and I'm not seeing any `unicast` options for wake-on-lan in the [Ubuntu docs for NetworkManager](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/snap-configuration/wowlan).  What's the equivalent setting to `unicast`?

Answer (score 1):

The docs I was looking for were for `wifi.wake-on-lan` not `802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan`.  For the latter the options are the same as with `ethtool` so you can just use `unicast`.

*lesson: sometimes it's ok to try it yourself and see what works*.