# Wake-on-LAN via SSH and Suspend problem

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, suspend, wake-on-lan

I am triying to wake-on-line via SSH. I have done it once but after I suspend remote desktop via `sudo systemctl suspend` suspend, I can not do it again.

All steps I have done is from [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421325/wake-on-lan-via-ssh).

I think, my first problem is `ethtool enp5s | grep wake-on` returns `Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted`. When I do it with `sudo`, it works:

```bsh
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: u
```

The `u` means *u (unicast activity),* and I think this is what i need for wake-on via SSH. Here is the problem: When I run `systemctl suspend` with wake-on: u configuration, system suspend and for a second and reopen. What should I do?

```
------------ UBUNTU VERSION ------------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa"
------------------------
------------ MINT VERSION ------------
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20
Release:    20
Codename:   ulyana
```

EDIT1: Interestingly, `sudo pm-suspend` works perfectly to suspend my computer (not reopen), but when I try to wake-on via ssh it is not wake-on. The weird thing is, it converts my `Wake-on` parameter from `u` to `g`.

Comment: The commands provided in the link start with a "#" meaning you are root. So, `sudo` is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

and sorry for being so late.

There are known problems with pm-utils...
see [debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan).

> [...]
>
> ## Troubleshooting WOL
>
> [...] However, if you do want Wake On LAN on any of these events
> (other than "Magic Packet"), you may find conflicts with pm-utils. At
> the time of writing, scripts in this package will set the wake option
> for all relevant interface cards to "Magic Packet" only, (g). This
> will be a problem if you want your machine to wake "on-demand", when
> it receives traffic (u), for example. The issue and a fix is discussed
> below.  [...]

and a [solution](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan#PM-Utils_Conflicts) consist to add a `/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol` file containing no more than "`exit 0`" to overide the `/usr/lib/pmutils/power.d/disable_wol` file and stay persistent while updating packages.

Greetings

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solve my problem with using `pm-suspend`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. My PC was configurated for WoWLAN. I used `wakeonlan <MAC>` command to wake up and `systemctl suspend` instead of `pm-suspend`.

In the case of `pm-suspend` my PC fans were starting every time I sent a wake package but sometimes I couldn't connect to the PC with ssh, ping its address and I had black screen when I attached the monitor.
The solution was to create `/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service` with content:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

and activating the script `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service`

I had to change `network-manager.service` in the script to `snap.network-manager.networkmanager.service` ([my WoWLAN config](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/wake-on-wlan)). The correct name you can check in `/etc/systemd/system/` directory. There is also `suspend.service` which explains why it works with `systemctl suspend` and doesn't work with `pm-suspend`